# VB 2010 Program fails Publishing

Tags: vb.net

I built a program using VB net 2010 named Parts Manager 3, when I debug the program it works but when I try to publish it the following errors are generated:

Error   1   Cannot publish because a project failed to build.       line 1; row1    Parts Manager 3

Error   2   Unable to remove directory "bin\Debug\app.publish\". Access to the path 'setup.exe' is denied.  Parts Manager 3

Anyone has any Idea why that happen and how can I correct them.

Thank you

Stefano

Comment: I have also this Warning appearing:                          Warning 2 Item 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)' already includes 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64)'. Parts Manager 3

Comment: Sounds like anti-malware trouble.  Make an exclusion for your project directory.

Comment: How could I do that my firewall is off and when I open defender I can just find the malaware link for the website

Comment: Hi everyone, I have fixed the problem by rewriting the code . It is not the most elegant solution but it worked

Comment: close your visual studio and delete debug folder and open your visual studio and then build your app

Answer (score -1):

As I have said in my comment I have fixed the problem recreating a new application copying step by step all forms and codes.
It is not elegant maybe but it worked for me
Thanks